# How to simplify combined data

Tags: list-manipulation, data

Let's consider the following sample data

```
data = {{0.54106280      -416.66667000     0.1146249816891388E+01      0      8      6},
        {0.61835749      -372.22222000     0.6319693889170223E+00      0      2      1},
        {0.30917874       -16.66666700     0.2790560888497788E+00      0     18     15},
        {5.71980680       350.00000000     0.2327036789870881E+00      0     32     20},
        {6.10628020       350.00000000     0.5786771357367857E+00      0      0      0},
        {6.18357490       566.66667000     0.5117201288823356E+00      0     10      5}};
```

We are only interested in the last two entries of each row. What I want is to reduce the two numbers to the simplest output. For example, 8 6 should become 4  3, 18  15 should become 6  5, and so on. Obviously, the already simplified ones (e.g., 2  1, 0  0) should remain unchanged. So, we need a new data list containing the same four entries of `data` and the simplified outputs of the last two columns.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Does this do it? `last2=Map[Take[#,-2]&,data]; last2reduced=Map[#/(GCD@@#)&,last2]` There are lots of other ways of extracting those last two columns and even doing the GCD. Just pick any one way that you can practice until you have memorized it and can do it without making a mistake.

Comment: @Bill not exactly. In case of 0  0 the code reports error "Infinite expression 1/0 encountered".

Comment: Oops. Missed that one. Thank you for catching my mistake. See if this fixes it. `last2reduced=Map[(g=GCD@@#;If[g==0,#,#/g])&,last2]`

Comment: @Bill Now it's working. Please post an answer so as to accept it. Also I want a new list `data2` containing the first 4 elements and replacing the last two with the reduced ones..

Comment: The following changes data to the table you want: data[[All, {-2, -1}]] /= (GCD @@@ (data[[All, {-2, -1}]]) /. 0 -> 1);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your data is not in a good shape for the syntax. If you input `data` as so in Mathematica, the space between them will turn into multiplication, every floating number will be assigned the machine precision, and the third column with the `E` will turn into Euler's $\mathrm{e}$. To prevent such and preserve them, the first thing you should do is making Mathematica interpret `data` as string data. Personally, I created `data.csv` accommodating the data. And then:

```
data = Flatten[StringSplit /@ Import["data.csv"], 1]

(*  {{"0.54106280", "-416.66667000", "0.1146249816891388E+01", "0", "8", "6"},
    {"0.61835749", "-372.22222000", "0.6319693889170223E+00", "0", "2", "1"},
    {"0.30917874", "-16.66666700", "0.2790560888497788E+00", "0", "18", "15"},
    {"5.71980680", "350.00000000", "0.2327036789870881E+00", "0", "32", "20"},
    {"6.10628020", "350.00000000", "0.5786771357367857E+00", "0", "0", "0"},
    {"6.18357490", "566.66667000", "0.5117201288823356E+00", "0", "10", "5"}}  *)

data2 = Module[{e56 = ToExpression[#[[5 ;; 6]]], gcd},
         gcd = GCD @@ e56;
         If[gcd != 0, ToString /@ Flatten@{#[[1 ;; 4]], e56/gcd}, #]
] & /@ data

(*  {{"0.54106280", "-416.66667000", "0.1146249816891388E+01", "0", "4", "3"},
     {"0.61835749", "-372.22222000", "0.6319693889170223E+00", "0", "2", "1"},
     {"0.30917874", "-16.66666700", "0.2790560888497788E+00", "0", "6", "5"},
     {"5.71980680", "350.00000000", "0.2327036789870881E+00", "0", "8", "5"},
     {"6.10628020", "350.00000000", "0.5786771357367857E+00", "0", "0", "0"},
     {"6.18357490", "566.66667000", "0.5117201288823356E+00", "0", "2", "1"}}  *)
```

To export, do `Export["data2.csv", data2, "Table"]`. In my notepad, it looks like the following:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

```
alist = Transpose[data[[All, 1 ;; -3]]]
blist = Transpose[(If[# =!= {0, 0}, #/GCD @@ #, #]) & /@ 
   data[[All, -2 ;; -1]]]
Transpose[alist~Join~blist] // TableForm
```

$$\left(
\begin{array}{cccccc}
 0.541063 & -416.667 & 1.14625 & 0 & 4 & 3 \\
 0.618357 & -372.222 & 0.631969 & 0 & 2 & 1 \\
 0.309179 & -16.6667 & 0.279056 & 0 & 6 & 5 \\
 5.71981 & 350. & 0.232704 & 0 & 8 & 5 \\
 6.10628 & 350. & 0.578677 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 6.18357 & 566.667 & 0.51172 & 0 & 2 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$